# How does the Simplex method of solving LPs use the starting solution?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming, numerical-linear-algebra

Say one looks at the LP (in slack form) and sees that assigning $0$s to all the non-basic variables doesn't give a valid solution but some other non-trivial assignment of values to the non-basic variables does form a valid assignment.

How (or Can) the Simplex method exploit such an observation?

Can you kindly give or link to some such example?

Comment: The Simplex method needs a feasible basic starting solution. If the zero-vector is not feasible, you could use the Big M-method or a Two-Phase Simplex algorithm to find a feasible basic solution.

Comment: @NigelOvermars Say I simply guessed a valid assignment of values to the non-basic variables such that the constraints are satisfied. This guess happens to be such that it doesn't assign $0$ to all my non-basic variables. Now how do I run the simplex using this guess? Where does the simplex algorithm exploit this find of mine?

Answer (score 0):

If you know a feasible solution, it's easy to either find a basic feasible solution with at least as good objective value, and then start the simplex method from there, or show the problem is
unbounded.  Namely, if $S$ is the set of  variables (including slack variables) with value $0$ in your feasible solution,
move from that feasible solution in a direction where the variables in $S$ stay $0$ and the objective increases until some other variable hits $0$.  Then add that variable to $S$ and continue.

EDIT

Here's a small example.  Suppose you want to maximize $f = x_1 + 2 x_2 + 3 x_3$ subject to 
$$ \eqalign{
    x_1 - x_2 + s_1 &= 3\cr
    -x_1 + x_3 + s_2 &= 4\cr
    x_1 + x_2 - x_3 + s_3 &= 1\cr
x_1,x_2,x_3,s_1,s_2,s_3 &\ge 0} $$
and you happen to notice that $x_1 = 1, x_2 = 1, x_3 = 1, s_1 = 3, s_2 = 4, s_3 = 0$ is a feasible solution.

The only variable that is $0$ here is $s_3$.  Let's move from that solution 
in a direction where $s_3$ stays $0$.  We can take $x_1 = 1 - t$, $x_2 = 1 + t$, $x_3 = 1$ (which keeps $s_3 = 0$), $s_1 = 3 - x_1 + x_2 = 3 + 2 t$,
$s_2 = 4 + x_1 - x_3 = 4 - t$, and $f = 6 + t$.  Since we want to increase the
objective, we let $t$ increase.  We find that $x_1$ hits $0$ at $t = 1$. 
At this point we have $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 2$, $x_3 = 1$, $s_1 = 5$, $s_2 = 3$, $s_3 = 0$, $f = 7$.

Now let's try changing $x_2$, keeping $x_1 = 0$ and $s_3 = 0$.  The equations (with $x_1 = 0$ and $s_3 = 0$) say
$$ \eqalign{
     - x_2 + s_1 &= 3\cr
      x_3 + s_2 &= 4\cr
      x_2 - x_3  &= 1\cr}$$
so if we take $x_2 = 2 + t$ we'll have $s_1 = 5 + t$, $x_3 = 1+t$, $s_2 = 3-t$
and $f = 7 + 5 t$.  So again let $t$ increase and we hit $s_2 = 0$ at $t = 3$.
At this point $x_1 = 0$, $x_2 = 5$, $x_3 = 4$, $s_1 = 8$, $s_2 = 0$, $s_3 = 0$ and $f = 22$.

The equations with $x_1 = 0$, $s_2 = 0$ and $s_3 = 0$ don't permit any changes, so our process of improvement has finished.  We now rewrite the system so $x_2, x_3, s_1$ are the basic variables and $x_1, s_2, s_3$ are nonbasic (this can be done with a pivot operation where $s_1$ enters the basis and $x_2$ leaves), 
and start the simplex method from there.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question. Can you kindly see the comment that I wrote above?

Comment: I did understand the question, and I answered it.  I'll see if I can find an example to make it clearer to you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this very helpful example! This is the only one of its kind that I found on the net! SO I guess the final form of the constraints from where one would start the simplex are $x_2 =  5 - s_2 - s_3, x_3 = 4+ x_1 - s_2, s_1 = 8 - x_1 - s_2 - s_3$

Comment: But I would like to know as to conceptually/geometrically what exactly happened here - as in why did we need to shift this into this new form of the constraint equations? What is conceptually special about this new point $x_1 = 0, x_3 = 4, x_2 = 5$ as compared to the initial choice of $x_1 = x_2 = x_3 = 1$ ? What really happened?

Comment: Also there is this other issue - as to if one is given a LP where the basic variables being set to zero is not feasible then one needs to solve a separate LP of the form $max \{-x_0\}, s_i = x_0 + (b_i - \sum_j a_{ij} x_j)$ where $i$ and $j$ go over the basic and the non-basic variables respectively and $x_0$ is a new non-negative variable that is introduced.  The point being that this new non-trivial solution itself is found by running this LP to see if $x_0$ can be sent to zero and then the corresponding assignment to the non-basic variables is taken. (on which one will do what you did)

Comment: There is no "other issue".  The "phase I" using the extra variable $x_0$ is just one method to find a basic solution that is feasible.  If you already know a feasible solution, then as I outlined you can find a basic feasible solution, and you don't need "phase I".

Comment: Geometrically, the basic feasible solutions correspond to extreme points of the convex set of feasible solutions.  The method I outlined starts with a feasible solution and moves within the convex set until either hitting an extreme point or a ray that shows the problem is unbounded.